# Counting length of string allocated dynamically using strlen

Tags: c, string, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am a newbie in programming. Here in the code below, I used strlen() to find length of string but every time in "Clion" is always give a result an extra 1.I mean if I input 11 character it's length shows 12(in the photo).How ever in "Compiler Explorer" it shows the correct result. Is this because of my code or IDE problem?

```
    char *ar5 = malloc(sizeof(char) * 257);
    fgets(ar5, sizeof(char) * 257, stdin);
    int lenar5 = strlen(ar5);
    printf("Length ar5 = %d\n", lenar5);
```

[Here is the Clion Result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnsMM.jpg)

[Here is the Compiler Explorer Result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQSbw.jpg)

Here the Compiler Explorer seems to give desired result but Clion isn't. Is there any other solution to find the length rather than using loops?

Comment: `fgets` will include the newline that is added to the input buffer by the `Enter` key. If you didn't end the compiler explorer input with a newline, then there's no newline to add.

Comment: `fgets` will leave a `\n` character at the end of the string which needs to be removed to get the expected result, see the linked duplicate.

Comment: @Dragon Emperor, "if I input 11 character it's length shows 12" --> The enter key `'\n'` is a character too.  Did you count that in "I input 11 character"?

Comment: Side-note: `sizeof(char)` is defined by the language standard to always be `1`. Writing it explicitly only creates visual clutter.

Comment: And yeah compiler explorer -> execution only -> stdin will not send a new line unless you type the input and then press enter. See this https://godbolt.org/z/xTYh8W6v7. I pressed enter after typing "hello" and then the input ends with 0x0A = '\n'.